# Django How to FormView rename context object?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a class view which uses **FormView**. I need to change the name of the form i.e. this is what it used to be in my old function view:

```
 upload_form = ContactUploadForm(request.user)
 context = {'upload': upload_form,}
```

With my new view I'm assuming I can rename using the get_context_data method but unsure how.

How can I rename this form to **upload** instead of **form** as my templates uses `{{ upload }}` not `{{ form }}`? Thanks.

Current Class View:

```
class ImportFromFile(FormView):

    template_name = 'contacts/import_file.html'
    form_class = ContactUploadForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Get the context for this view.
        """
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context.
        context = super(ImportFromFile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        return context
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ImportFromFile(FormView):

    template_name = 'contacts/import_file.html'
    form_class = ContactUploadForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Get the context for this view.
        """
        kwargs['upload'] = kwargs.pop('form')
        return super(ImportFromFile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Django 2.0+ provides support for changing context object names. See: [Built-in class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)

> **Making “friendly” template contexts**
>
> You might have noticed that our sample publisher list template stores all the publishers in a variable named object_list. While this works just fine, it isn’t all that “friendly” to template authors: they have to “just know” that they’re dealing with publishers here.
>
> Well, if you’re dealing with a model object, this is already done for you. When you are dealing with an object or queryset, Django is able to populate the context using the lowercased version of the model class’ name. This is provided in addition to the default object_list entry, but contains exactly the same data, i.e. publisher_list.
>
> If this still isn’t a good match, you can manually set the name of the context variable. The `context_object_name` attribute on a generic view specifies the context variable to use:

```
class PublisherList(ListView):
    model = Publisher
    context_object_name = 'choose the name you want here'
```

Comment: This doesn't work with a form object, it still remains "form" in context